# Using only the year part of a date for a WHERE condition

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In the LINQ statement below, I want to select people with an exam date in 2010. The exam date is stored as a datetime as the actual date and time is used in other applications. What is the most elegant, easiest, best way to compare the exzam date to only '2010'. Or, should I just compare, using >=, the exam date to 1/1/2010?

```
var active = dc.People.Where(x => x.exam >= 2010)
        .Select(x => new {x.ContactID, x.FirstName, x.LastName})
                   );

x.MostRecent == DateTime.Parse("1/1/2010").Year
```

EDIT #1

I thought I should see a .Year on the exam date but I didn't. After seeing a couple of posts here I went back and found this works...

```
.Where(x => x.exam.Value.Year == 2010)
```

Why is .Value necessary to access .Year? Exam is a nullable datetime.

Comment: `.Value` is necessary because `exam` is a nullable field in your model. (I presume in your database the corresponding column allows NULLs.)

Comment: @Scott - That's correct, the DB allows nulls in that column. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can just use the `Year` property on `DateTime`:

```
var active = from p in dc.People
             where p.Exam.Year >= 2010
             select new {
                 p.ContactID,
                 p.FirstName,
                 p.LastName
             };
```

> Why is .Value necessary to access .Year? Exam is a nullable datetime.

Exactly because `Exam` is a `Nullable<DateTime>`. When you declare an instance of `Nullable<DateTime>` like

```
DateTime? exam;
```

note that `exam` is not a `DateTime` and therefore you can't directly access the properties of `DateTime`. To get a concrete instance of `DateTime` you use the `Value` property on `Nullable<DateTime>` (all `Nullable<T>`s have this property) so that

```
DateTime instance = exam.Value;
```

is a `DateTime` assuming that `exam` is not `null`. You can therefore say

```
int year = instance.Year;
```

and, of course, for brevity

```
int year = exam.Value.Year;
```

Note that this will throw if `exam.HasValue` is false.

Comment: @SpecialAgent_W436: Exactly because `People.Exam` is a `Nullable<DateTime>` (aka, `DateTime?`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the most elegant way but this is the simplest way you can do it assuming examdate is the datetime col which you store your date and based on `I want to select people with an exam date in 2010`-

```
var active = dc.People.Where(x => x.examdate.year == 2010)
        .Select(x => new {x.ContactID, x.FirstName, x.LastName})
                   );
```