# Search by month and year in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this method where I want to get all inserted records in Database passing month and year. I want to filter the DB by passed month and year. This is what I tried but returns nothing:

```
//The model
public class HomeVM
{
    public string Tecnico { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Mese { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Search(HomeVM homeVM)
{
   var tecnico = _db.Tecnici
       .Where(m => m.Id == homeVM.Attivita.Tecnico)
       .Select(m => m.Surname+ " " + m.Name)
       .FirstOrDefault();

   var month= homeVM.Mese;

   var result = _db.VW_ATTIVITA_DAILY.Where(m => m.Data == month && m.Tecnico == tecnico).ToList();       
}
```

`result` is 0, the result is not right.

How can I get all inserted records passing month and year?

Comment: Possible duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694352/using-only-the-year-part-of-a-date-for-a-where-condition

Comment: I know that there are full of examples, but in my case [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694352/using-only-the-year-part-of-a-date-for-a-where-condition) did not solve anything. In SQL works fine but I'm doing something wrong in EF and I can't get why is not working

Comment: `var result = _db.VW_ATTIVITA_DAILY.Where(m => m.Data == mese && m.Tecnico == tecnico).ToList();` what is `mese` here? Did you mean `month` or `homeVM.Mese`?

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to update that part. It should be :   `var result = _db.VW_ATTIVITA_DAILY.Where(m => m.Data == month && m.Tecnico == tecnico).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
public IActionResult Search(HomeVM homeVM)
{
   var tecnico = _db.Tecnici
       .Where(m => m.Id == homeVM.Attivita.Tecnico)
       .Select(m => m.Surname+ " " + m.Name)
       .FirstOrDefault();

   var result = _db.VW_ATTIVITA_DAILY.Where(m =>
 m.Data.Year == homeVM.Mese.Year
  &&m.Data.Month == homeVM.Mese.Month 
 && m.Tecnico == tecnico).ToList();       
}
```

m.Tecnico == tecnico looks very suspisous to me too. I would like to see your
VW_ATTIVITA_DAILY and Tecnici EF classes

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed